# Orientation of gravity force in energy

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, work, potential-energy

My apologies in advance if this is a stupid question.

> A 0.20 kg rocket in a fireworks display is launched from rest and follows an erratic flight path
> to reach the point P, which is 29 meters above the starting point. In the process, 425 Joules of work is done on the rocket by the nonconservative force generated by the burning propellant. Ignoring air resistance and the mass lost due to the burning propellant, find the speed of the rocket at the point P.

This would be a standard computation using a variant of the work energy theorem, where for mass $m$, initial height $h_0$, initial velocity $v_0$, final height $h_f$ and final velocity $v_f$, we have
$$W_{\text{nonconservative force}}=\Delta E_{\text{kinetic}} + \Delta E_{\text{grav pot}}=\left(\frac12 mv_f^2-\frac12 mv_0^2\right)+\left(mgh_f-mgh_0\right)$$
define the initial position of the rocket as $h=0$, then the initial gravitational potential energy is $0$, as well as the initial kinetic energy. Hence,
$$\implies 425 = \frac 12\cdot 0.2\cdot v_f^2 + 0.2\cdot g\cdot29$$
What do I plug in for $g$? $g=9.8$ m/s^2 or $g=-9.8$ m/s^2?

I can't seem to reason this out. Gravitational potential energy is defined $0$ at infinity but somehow the wikipedia article seems to say the $mgh$ formula comes from defining $0$ at $h=0$.  But regardless of which, both coordinate systems have gravity pointing downwards so I would be inclined to think the negative choice was the way to go, but the actual correct answer plugs in the positive choice.

What am I misunderstanding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say it is more typical in physics to take $g$ as a positive constant, and use the coordinate system in the individual problem to determine direction or sign. After all, $g$ is derived from:

$$F = m\frac{GM_{Earth}}{R_{Earth}^2}=mg
$$

and so it is composed of positive constants.

As another user stated, potential energy should get higher (more positive or less negative) as an object moves upwards in a gravitational field (i.e. against the force of gravity). Apply this to your problem.  In particular, your $\Delta E_{Grav\,Pot}$ term means $E_{final}-E_{initial}$.  In your scenario should this change be positive or negative?

Comment: Ah i see yea this makes sense. We defined potential to be 0 at the surface so the potential when raising upwards should be positive. we would take the positive constant for g

Answer (score 0):

Sign your equation and/or define your constants so that you have more potential energy at higher height, matching observable reality.

Perhaps think of the textbook's apparent sloppiness as practice in the importance of actually analyzing physical systems and explicitly defining your own terms, rather than blindly plugging values into equations.

Comment: wait could you elaborate on the first part?