# Why is gravity positive in this scenario?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, rotational-dynamics

[image: Solution]

I am working on some simple tasks ahead of my exam in physics. But I can't wrap my head around this one... I understand that the speed on the top of the rise has to be smaller than the start speed - but I don't understand the algebra or reasoning og whatever behind g not being -9.8? Since the minus sign inside the root doesn't change to plus?

Comment: In the equation, is mgh positive or negative? If g is negative, then what is h?

Comment: Check this out https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/728905/313823

Answer (score 3):

The number $g$ is just the positive number $9.8 \mathrm{\ m/s^2}$. The vector $\vec g$ is a vector with magnitude $g$ whose direction points downward. Whether that is positive or negative depends on the coordinate system chosen.

So, in this particular problem, remember, for a conservative force $\vec F$ $$\vec F = -\nabla U$$ where $U$ is the potential energy associated with the force. So since a gravity is conservative if we adopt a coordinate system where the $z$ axis is pointing upwards we can write $$\vec F = (0,0,-mg)$$ so here we see that the gravity vector points downward with a magnitude of $mg$. Then, recognizing that $$(0,0,-mg)=-\nabla(mgz)$$$$U=mgz=mgh$$ we see that the negative sign on the gravitational force is "canceled" by the negative sign in front of the $\nabla$ operator, so $mgh$ is positive, or rather the gravitational potential energy $mgh$ increases as you go upwards.